# Trying to de-code "dsetg nvxgn..."

Tags: cipher

The code is:

> dsetg nvxgn abfus fcaur vvkyq llszs yybik pkefa vbyjj stalk aupoc dvyai qnlrj iewzb qfcct mgqrg xxuqy sapeb reahl btxbz wisfd klbqr letxa zhu

I've run it through a bunch of ciphers and can't find any solution. I believe the spaces count as characters, too.

A user in a chat room at my work posted this and said "decode this and win a prize" basically. Another user said the spaces are significant, and he is typically pretty smart so I figured I'd go with what he said.

Comment: No more details? ;)

Comment: Please attribute your puzzle: https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/a-policy-on-plagiarism

Comment: Please read this meta question: https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do

Comment: @Bass Most of the advice there is for people *composing* code/cipher puzzles, whereas it seems Trajer has run across one made by someone else and is looking for help with figuring it out.

Comment: @Trajer As humfuzz says, we do need to know where this comes from -- and that may also be useful information for solving it. If all we have is 118 letters (I bet you're wrong about the spaces being significant) with no sort of context, it's going to be tough.

Comment: I've deleted the "answer" whose content F1Krazy has helpfully edited into the question -- I assume it was posted by the same person who posted the question.

Comment: I'm going to guess that the "spaces are significant" is simply due to the fact that they separate the letters into groups of 5. Such groupings of 5 do not, however, reduce the space to something manageable as many ciphers in use in the early 20th century (WWI and WWII) grouped things in such a way. Significantly, though, a Polybius Square makes use of groupings of 5, so this might be useful as an interpretation of the significance of the groupings.

Comment: If you really want to help, maybe mention the ciphers you did try (so we don't waste time on them)?